# Initialise array to null objects

Tags: arrays, ada

I have an Employee package and an Office package, say. The Office package has an array of Employee objects. I can declare the array so that

```
officeArray : Office.Vector(1..20);
```

But how would I initialise `officeArray` to a set of 20 null objects? I tried

```
officeArray := (others => null);
```

This does not work. The compiler says it wants Employee objects. I can create a dummy Employee object to fill the array, or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Is it an array of access types or not?

Comment: We would be able to help you much better if you showed us the declaration of - at least - `Office.Vector`.

Comment: And the declaration of `Employee`.  Whatever that declaration is, _you will have to define for yourself_ what it means for an `Employee` to be a "null" employee.  Assuming an `Employee` is a record, there's no built-in definition of a "null" value of that record, any more than there's a built-in definition of a "null" `Integer`.

Comment: Note that - unlike (say) common C++ practice, an array of objects would store the objects themselves, not references to them (access types, or pointers), and while `null` is a valid value for an access type, there is naturally no inherent concept of a null object (record, tagged record), you have to declare one in the Office package. As Ondrej's answer shows, you *could* handle access types instead, but that is rarely the best choice.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a sample program:

```
With Ada.Text_IO; Use Ada.Text_IO;  
With Ada.Integer_Text_IO; Use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Program is

  type Employee is record
      name : String(1..50);
      end record;

  type EmployeeArr is array (Positive range <>) of Employee;

  type EmployeePtr is access all Employee;

  type EmployeePtrArr is array (Positive range <>) of EmployeePtr;

  employees1 : EmployeeArr(1..20);
  employees2 : EmployeePtrArr(1..20);

begin
  employees1 := (others => null); -- this will NOT compile
  employees2 := (others => null); -- this compiles fine
end Program;
```

In order to assign `(others => null)` the array's element type must be an access type.